# Fix position of force-graph node using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, d3-force-directed

I'm using a `force-graph` D3 visualization from https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph. This seems to provide great high-level API to create a force directed graph but I find it hard to customise as I'm new to Javascript.

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/force-graph"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>

fetch('data.json').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      const Graph = ForceGraph()
      (document.getElementById('graph'))
        .graphData(data)
        .nodeAutoColorBy('group')
        .linkSource('source')
        .linkTarget('target')
})

</script>
```

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to fix the position of a particular node, for example `id = Myriel` to `x=500`, `y=500`. According to d3 force [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force), I need to specify `fx` and `fy`. How do I retrieve the id of the particular node to set the those attributes? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you upload your interactive chart to blockbuilder or codepen.io so your question will get more attention?

Comment: If I'm using external libraries (such as the force-graph) in the repo, will it work on sites like blockbuilder/codepen?

Comment: yes, you can use cdn links

Comment: You should be able to just set the fx and fy properties in your data: `{"id": "Myriel", "group": 1, "fx":500, "fy":500},`

Comment: @AndrewReid I really, really wished this worked because it seems so simple! Unfortunately it didn't :(

Comment: It [should](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/4e2db5af8957770545a911042980b0b2).

Comment: @AndrewReid That's interesting, I see you're using the d3-force directly -- I'm actually using [this](https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph) and it didn't seem to register the attributes from the data. Do you know if there is any way to do so using this?

Comment: Ah yes, I read too quickly (and looked at the answer, which suggests an alternative vanilla d3 approach) - can't say I've seen that implementation, though, it was worth seeing if it would register `fx` and `fy` properties. Not sure how one would adapt that with that implementation: it may be trading off customization for ease of use, nothing in the docs really hit me as an obvious solution.

Comment: @AndrewReid If it helps, there is a [onNodeDragEnd](https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph/blob/master/example/fix-dragged-nodes/index.html) which can set the `fx` and `fy` properties when the node is dragged/end! How do I trigger this on start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
.nodeVal(node => {         
  node.fx = 500;
  node.fy = 500
})
```

Using the `nodeVal` method, I can access the attributes of the nodes to fix it. Adding a `if` statement would allow me to change it only if it the specific nodes I need. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The API link that you've provided is really beautiful.  It's such a complex chart to work with and it ticks almost every box.

However, it looks like the only way to adapt it to YOUR needs would be to hack into the js code which I would not advise.

Personally I would start with a simpler d3 version and customise from here.

For example:  https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph

Here, you'd need to customise the simulation.on("tick" function.  Something like this:

```
node
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    **.attr("fx", d => d.id === "Myrial" ? 500 : null)**
    **.attr("fy", d => d.id === "Myrial" ? 500 : null);**
```

`

OR for a similar approach to your example you could use Vega.  That allows you to use fx and fy:

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/force/

Comment: I'm actually using a much more complex customisation (code above is simplified) using the force-graph library I provided - It would take me a very long time to start from scratch. I'm convinced there is a way to retrieve the node to set its attribute using JS, but I'm new to all these..